# Does existence of two Killing vectors $X,Y$ with $[X,Y]\neq 0$ imply existence of a third linearly independent Killing vector?

Tags: differential-geometry

Suppose we have a Riemannian or Lorentzian manifold with two Killing vector fields $X,Y$ such that $[X,Y]\neq 0$. Does this imply existence of a third linearly independent Killing vector field $Z$?

I know that $[X,Y]$ is itself a Killing vector. But e.g. for $\mathbb{H}^2$, one can choose the Killing vectors to satisfy $[H,J_+]=J_+$, $[H,J_-]=-J_-$ and $[J_+,J_-]=2H$, so we see that $[X,Y]$ does not generally provide a linearly independent Killing vector.

A minimal counter-example to my claim would be to find a manifold with exactly two Killing vectors $X,Y$ satisfying $[X,Y]\neq 0$, but I seem to be unable to find such a manifold.

**EDIT:** my original claim included further requirements on $Z$, namely that $[Z,X]\neq 0$ and $[Z,Y]\neq 0$. These follow IF we can prove the existence of a linearly independent Killing vector $Z$. Then, if e.g. $[Z,X]=0$ and $[Z,Y]\neq 0$, consider $Z^\prime = Z+Y$ which is a linearly independent Killing vector with $[Z^\prime,X]=[Y,X]\neq 0$ and $[Z^\prime,Y]=[Z,Y]\neq 0$. Finally, if both $[Z,X]=0$ and $[Z,Y]= 0$, consider $Z^{\prime\prime}=Z+X+Y$, so that $[Z^{\prime\prime},X]=[Y,X]\neq 0$ and $[Z^{\prime\prime},Y]=[X,Y]\neq 0$.

Comment: What's wrong with $X+Y$? I guess you want the third one to be linearly independent?

Comment: Ah, sure, thanks for spotting this!

Comment: Actually, suppose $[X,Y]$ is nonzero, but s.t. $[Y,[X,Y]] = 0$ and $[X,[X,Y]] = V \neq 0$. Then let $Z = [X,Y]+cX$; so $[Y,Z] = c[X,Y]$ and $[X,Z] = V + cX$. You can pick $c$ so that both of these are nonzero, and then provided $[X,Y]$ is linearly independent of $X$ and $Y$, this satisfies what we want.

Comment: Don't we have $[X,Z]=[X,[X,Y]]+[X,cX]=V$ rather than $V+cX$?

Comment: Sorry, I'm confused: what is $X+cY$?

Comment: I'm being horrible this morning... $V+cY$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/32008/discussion-between-kuba-and-mike-miller).